# Rsync unexprected behavior

Tags: bash, rsync, file-copy, macos

I have 2 external drives and I want to use `rsync` to copy the files that have been updated (modified timestamp) in the source directory to a target directory.

The files have the same filename but the timestamp is different i.e. some files have been recently updated but the filename has remained the same.

However,

`rsync -rv --ignore-existing --progress /Volumes/vol1/Data/ /Volumes/vol2/Data/`

does not do anything. The result is null nothing is transferred.

> sending incremental file list
>
> sent 68 bytes  received 12 bytes  160.00 bytes/sec total size is
> 20,634  speedup is 257.93

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you think `--ignore-existing` does? Also, if you rely on the timestamps, you may want to actually update the timestamps too.  This is done by changing `-r` to `-a` (which _includes_ `-r`).

Comment: @they I expect `--ignore-existing` to ignore same filenames with *same* timestamps. If the timestamp has changed then it should copy (update) the file.

Comment: The default behavior is ignoring files with identical timestamps and names (and size).

Comment: the size and timestamp have changed. only the name remains the same and the command fails to update the modified files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Reading The Fine Manual I find this:

```
        --ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```

So by definition, the options you're using are explicitly asking NOT to update already existing files.

I think you simply want to use "-a" (archive) option:

```
rsync -av --progress /Volumes/vol1/Data/ /Volumes/vol2/Data/
```

Comment: will this skip identical files with identical timestamps or will copy everything?

Comment: @seralouk yes it will skip files with the same exact size and timestamp.

Comment: thanks -- accepted.